# Javascript For loop appending child only appends first element, then throws error

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, appendchild

I'm looping through a js object with a nested for loop, stated below, it appends the first element correctly, but then throws the following error:
`Can't set the property className of an undefined reference or empty reference.` (not sure if exact error, translating from Dutch...)

```
function allVideos() {
    var sql = "SELECT videos.VideoName, videos.VideoPath FROM videos";
    var resultSet = db.query(sql, {json:true}); //returns: [{"VideoName":"timelapse aethon2","VideoPath":"videos\\Roermond Papier\\160424 Time laps Aethon2.avi"},{"VideoName":"timelapse aethon3","VideoPath":"videos\\Roermond Papier\\160424 Time laps Aethon2.avi"}]
    var parsed = JSON.parse(resultSet);
    var parsedlength = arrLenght(parsed);
    //alert(resultSet);
    for(var i = 0; i < parsedlength; i++) {
        var obj = parsed[i];
        //alert(i);
        var videoElement = document.getElementById("allVideos");
        for (var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                videoElement.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
                videoElement.children[i].id='allVid' + i;
                videoElement.children[i].className='col-md-4 col-xs-12';
                //alert(typeof key)
                var card = document.getElementById('allVid' + i);
                alert(i);
                card.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
                card.children[i].className='card card-block';
                card.children[i].innerHTML = "<h3 class='card-title'>" + obj['VideoName'] + "</h3><button class='btn btn-primary'>Selecteren</button>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] added screenshot of how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some significant logic issues. You're using nested loops, but appending to an element assuming that the *outer* loop counter will let you index into that element's children to get the element you just appended. Later, you try to get that same element again using `getElementById`. Then, you append a new element to your newly-created element, but try to access that new element using `children[i]` on the one you just created — at that point, the `card` element will only have a single child, so as of the second outer loop, it will fail.

`createElement` returns the element to you, so there's no reason at all to try to access it via `children[i]` (either time) or `getElementById`.

See comments:

```
function allVideos() {
    var sql = "SELECT videos.VideoName, videos.VideoPath FROM videos";
    var resultSet = db.query(sql, {json:true});
    var parsed = JSON.parse(resultSet);
    var parsedlength = arrLenght(parsed);
    for(var i = 0; i < parsedlength; i++) {
        var obj = parsed[i];
        //alert(i);
        var videoElement = document.getElementById("allVideos");
        for (var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // Create the card, give it its id and class
                var card = document.createElement('div');
                card.id='allVid' + i;
                card.className='col-md-4 col-xs-12';

                // Create the div to put in the card, give it its class and content
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                card.appendChild(div);
                div.className='card card-block';
                div.innerHTML = "<h3 class='card-title'>" + obj['VideoName'] + "</h3><button class='btn btn-primary'>Selecteren</button>"

                // Append the card
                videoElement.appendChild(card);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Side note: `arrLenght` looks like a typo (it should be `th`, not `ht`), but moreover, there's no reason to use a function to get the length of an array; it's available via the array's `length` property: `parsedLength = parsed.length`.

Side note 2: You may find [these ways of looping through arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) useful.

Comment: oh, wow, I realise now how stupid that logic was indeed, your answer helped, though there is one very minor error in it, `videoElement.appendChild(card)` shouldn't be in the nested for loop, since this will cause doubles, instead, I put it in the 1st for loop.

Comment: @Luuk: If `videoElement.appendChild(card)` shouldn't be in the inner loop, we probably need to adjust the logic creating `card`...?

Comment: for some reason it works perfectly with `videoElement.appendChild(card)` outside of the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the if within the nested for:

```
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { ...
```

The variable `i` is increased even if the property is not "owned" (when the if condition returns false), so next time that the condition is true, `i` is out of bounds.

Comment: No, that's in the inner loop. It's true using `i` for indexing into `children` is a problem, but the main problem is trying to use it to index into an element that by definition only has one child.